# plot the histogram of purchases

Tags: r, plotting, histogram

i have a dataframe with 34154695 obs. in a dataset a Class variable with value 0 indicate "not purchased" and 1 indicate "purchase".

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   34154695 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ SessionID: int  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ Timestamp: Factor w/ 34069144 levels "2014-04-01T03:00:00.124Z",..: 1452469 1452684 1453402 1501801 1501943 1502207 1502429 1502569 1502932 295601 ...
 $ ItemID   : int  214536500 214536506 214577561 214662742 214662742 214825110 214757390 214757407 214551617 214716935 ...
 $ Category : Factor w/ 339 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Class    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I am facing difficulties finding a solution to plot a histogram of the number of purchase per week, per day and time wise purchase based on class value = 1 and wanna output like this.
[image]
[image]

Could someone please inform how I should proceed??
Really, thank you for any help and suggestings.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first of all, if you want to get aggregated data, you need to group it by day/week, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)



x <- strptime(data$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d")#assume you need only days/month , assign to a variable, because dplyr has problems with with date type.

data$month <- month(x) #get month from date obj.

month_summ <- data %>% group_by(month) %>%  #group by month and calculated sold items per month
  summarise(
    total_sales = n()
  )


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=month_summ, aes(x=month, y=total_sales)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity") #plot the histogram
```

This should do the work for you or act like a starting point. [Here is](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/) a good reference for ggplot2 bar plots

Hope this helps!

Comment: your code give this error Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `date` is of unsupported class POSIXlt/POSIXt

Comment: @mairakhan edited the post - can you please try it with your data?

Comment: ok sir  ....... :)

Comment: got error again ...... Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `date` is of unsupported class POSIXlt/POSIXt

Comment: @mairakhan You sure that you didnt include formated time into your DataFrame?

Comment: now got this error     > ggplot(data=month_summ, aes(x=month, y=ItemID)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity") #plot the histogram
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ItemID' not found

Comment: @mairakhan whoops, sorry if should be: 
ggplot(data=month_summ, aes(x=month, y=total_sales)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity")

Comment: great to hear it, you are welcome!

Comment: sir need your help again....how to plot clicks on a given item in a session, item duration in a session (seconds) and session duration (minutes) .

Comment: @mairakhan i think you can group_by (ItemID, SessionId) and calculate duration of a session with diiftime.  If you have big number of uqniue combinations of (ItemID, SessionId), bar plot would not be very informative though

Comment: sir can you plz provide me a syntax because i tried alot but I am facing difficulties :-(

Comment: @mairakhan I can, maybe its better to cominucate in skype? I guess this will be way more easier.